# lazy-init="true" on a LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean is ignored as of Spring 3.2

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-3

Set lazy-init="true" on a LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean gets ignored as of Spring 3.2. I have ported an application from Spring 3.0 to 3.2. The lazy init of the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean works fine in Spring 3.0 but not in 3.2.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
   class="de.gillardon.base.hibernate.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBean" 
   lazy-init="true">
    <property name="persistenceProviderClass" 
              value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties" ref="jpaProperties"/>
</bean>
```

I think the change was introduced with CS https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/3c59725b94faef83bbc3ca5d48f955aabe6ff9d0 for Spring v3.2.0.RC1.

In

```
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.
finishBeanFactoryInitialization(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory)
...
// Initialize LoadTimeWeaverAware beans early to allow for registering their transformers early.
String[] weaverAwareNames = beanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(LoadTimeWeaverAware.class, false, false);
for (String weaverAwareName : weaverAwareNames) {
    getBean(weaverAwareName);
}
```

As LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean implements LoadTimeWeaverAware it gets initialized even if lazy-init=true. Is this an **intended behavior or a bug**? I could not find any hint on this behavior in the documentation.

Comment: `lazy-init` only defers the init of beans to the moment they are requested from the context. Either by a bean that is referencing it, or when it is needed for auto wiring (with `@PersistentContext` for instance). Make sure that that isn't the case.

Comment: I know. But the application worked as intended with Spring 3.0.

Comment: It seems that [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9857) is the culprit here. You might want to add a comment to it or, better, create another JIRA issue mentioning the lazy-init side-effect that might need to be specified in either the API or documentation.